# Angular routing vs Ionic routing

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I'm new to ionic2. There is something weird in it's routing compared to pure angular routing. In Angular:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  // other imports here
],
```

We pass a constant with type of `Routes`.

In Ionic ([sidemenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) starter) they pass a component to `forRoot` function.

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
],
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Things have changed
https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**

Ionic 4 is also using standard angular routes in the background.Pushing and popping is not the ionic way anymore and [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/) is a good read on using angular router with ionic.

**Original Answer:**

Ionic does not support URL routes, instead it implements a custom navigation solution - [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) (as linked by suraj). NavController maintains a stack of pages - moving forward you push a page to the stack `this.nav.push(Page1);` and moving back you pop it `this.navCtrl.pop();`.
In this way your url in browser is always the same and application always opens on the home page - which is similar to mobile application behaviour. To enable direct access to a certain resource (as you would open url myapp/items/1) you have to use [deep linking plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/).

Comment: Which ionic version are you talking about? It is perfectly fine in the new Ionic (4+).

Answer (score 1):

In ionic, we push a view screen from another views

But in angular it is predefined routes mapping that if you go to this route i.e. app/login you will be redirected to login route that is bind with loginComponent